# Multi tenancy with Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, unity-container, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement this scenario using Unity and i can't figure out how this could be done:

the same web application (ASP.NET MVC) should be made accessible to more than one client (multi-tenant). The URL of the web site will differentiate the client (this i know how to get).

So getting the URL one could set the (let's call it) IConnectionStringProvider parameter (which will be afterward injected into IRepository and so on).
Through which mechanism (using Unity) do i set the IConnectionStringProvider parameter at run time?

I have done this in the past using Windsor & IHandlerSelector (see [this](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/11/multi-tenancy-part-2-components-and.html)) but it's my first attempt using Unity.

Any help is deeply appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you use Unity instead of Windsor?

Comment: Because of the "nature" of the problem. Client did not say that this *has* to be used, but pointed in this direction. BTW is this technique applicable if i use RIA services? (or should i open a new thread?)

Comment: AFAIK Unity does not provide this ability. Stick to Windsor if you have the chance. I have precisely 0 knowledge about RIA services so I suggest it's better to open a new thread and ask there.

Comment: How are you configuring your container? Via config or code?

Comment: I would like to use a separate config file (or at least the web.config file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i did what  Krzysztof Koźmic suggested. See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450069/windsor-ihandlerselector-in-ria-services-visual-studio-2010-beta2) for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can hard code parameters in Unity config, but you can't dynamically inject them at run time.  I believe this is coming in Unity 2.0, have you had a look at the Beta?